# WebRTC - No Streams Apparently Means No ICE Transitions

Tags: webrtc

WebRTC peer to peer setup works perfectly with both audio and video locally and remotely. The ICE connection state transitions as expected and finally lands in the "connected" state.

Now if I don't add any audio or video streams to the peer, the session descriptions and ice candidates are exchanged and applied successfully, but the ice connection state never changes to anything. Not to checking, connected, disconnect, failed, or closed. No exceptions are thrown either.

If I add just an audio stream, again everything is exchanged and applied successfully, and the ice connection state this time transitions to "checking" but nothing after that.

Any insight as to why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the SDP generated you'll see it has no m= sections. Those are necessary in order to have a=candidate lines and without those you can not establish a connection (and it would be surprising if you got candidates). There is some discussion around this issue [here](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/issues/1745).

For the second question the answer is "it depends". [This](https://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/) discusses how to use chrome's webrtc-internal for analysing the issue.

Comment: Ah! You are right! There are no m= sections for the streamless connection. Makes sense too with `m=` representing a _media stream description_ according to RFC3264.

I also tried audio-only in firefox (using about:webrtc for debugging) and the ice connection state transitioned into _connected_ as desired, so I guess it does depend.